# Posting to Servlet From Two Forms Within HTML Page

Tags: sql, html, servlets, jakarta-ee

Solution: Just added null default values to the HTML parameters. Seems to have solved it!

So I have an admin page (HTML) with two forms. First form is to add to an SQL database and has 4 input boxes, second form deletes from a SQL database and has 1 input box. If I use the first form, everything is OK. But if I leave the first form empty and just put a value for the 2nd form, I get an NumberFormatException for String = "" I can only assume because the first form is empty. I'm trying to have the user either fill the first form and leave the 2nd empty, or vice versa. Any advice on how to better approach this would be great.

This is my HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Admin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the admin page.</h1>
    <h2>Please enter the new product to be added:</h2>
        <form action="eShop" method="Post">
            <table class="tableBox">
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><b>Item Code:</b></td>
                <td align="left"><input type="number" name="code"></td>
            </tr>            
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><b>Item Name:</b></td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><b>Item Price:</b></td>
                <td align="left"><input type="number" name="price"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><b>Is Taxable:</b></td>
                <td align="left"><input type="text" name="taxable"></td>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="action" value="Update!"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        <h2>Enter the code of the product you want to delete:</h2>
        <form action="eShop" method="Post">
        <table class="tableBox">
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><b>Item Code:</b></td>
                <td align="left"><input type="number" name="code"></td>
            </tr>            
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="submit"  name="action" value="Delete!"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the section in my servlet that gets the parameters

```
else if(request.getParameter("action").equals("Delete!")) {
                DataAccessImpl temp = new DataAccessImpl();
                int code = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("code"));
                temp.deleteItem(code);
            }
```

This is the DataAccessImpl class used in the servlet, particularly the method that will delete the row.

```
public void deleteItem(int code) {
    connect();
    String deleteStm = ("DELETE FROM ProductCatalogue WHERE code = " + code);
    PreparedStatement pstm = null;
    System.out.println("Beginning to delete product from database...");
    try {
        pstm = conn.prepareStatement(deleteStm);
        System.out.println("Delete complete!");
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in first form name your submit button like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="updateAction" value="Update!">
```

in second form name your submit button like this:

```
<input type="submit"  name="deleteAction" value="Delete!">
```

Servlet Code should be like this:

```
else if(request.getParameter("deleteAction").equals("Delete!")) {
                DataAccessImpl temp = new DataAccessImpl();
                int code = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("code"));
                temp.deleteItem(code);
            }
```